# span to the right of an li

Tags: html, css

I am trying to span a text item to the right of an `li` list to show a message next to the the textbox.

```
<li class="name">
    <label for="name">Name:</label>
    <input type="text" name="name" id="name" />
    <span id="nameInfo"></span>
</li>
```

Message is only showing at the bottom of the textbox. Thanks.

Comment: Does your list have a specified width?

Comment: and what is happening right now?

Comment: are you leaving enough space for it?  It shows up to the right ok here: http://jsfiddle.net/F3srC/

Comment: what msg exactly? if nameInfo it seems to be right of the input see http://jsbin.com/agijax/1/edit

Comment: adjusted specified width of li and issue fixed

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using CSS assign enough width to *name* class

```
.name{
    width:300px;
}​
```

Try to set width to be 60px for example it obligatory will be rendered in ordered line.